# Как грамотно почистить базу перед/после автотестов?

Tags: python, тестирование, pytest, автоматизация, функциональное-тестирование

Нужен совет от опытных авто тестеров.

(вообще использую pytest)

Обычный пример:
Вот простой тест, один из тысячи, "сделать карточку товара" для вэб сайта магазина.
Сделал карточку "Носки для тенниса"

Тест упал, перезапускаю его, а уже нельзя имя занято.
(удалить карточку через апи или интерфейс нельзя, только заблокировь, вот такой пример)

Как авто тестировщики борються с такими ситуациями, бэкап базы выгружать каждый раз?

Самостоятельно писать sql запрос на удаление записи, а если там много зависимостей?

Подскажите может есть какой-то инструмент или подход для таких ситуаций?

Как оно вообще в боевых ситуациях?

Хотя бы общими словами, я погуглю

Comment: «бэкап базы выгружать каждый раз?» — ну типа того. Только «бэкап базы» по-моему не очень удачный термин, если посмотреть например на какой-нибудь [TransactionTestCase из Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase), то он заполняет базу фикстурами перед тестом и выполняет truncate таблиц после теста — по сути то же самое, но более грамотно сформулировано

Comment: Перед тестированием загрузите данные из бекапа. После тестирования сотрите базу.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такие понятия как ***test setup*** и ***test teardown*** - "подготовка к тестам" и "завершение тестов". Это действия, которые всегда выполняются перед и после собственно самих тестов (или группы тестов), независимо от результатов отдельных тестов. Смысл как раз в том, чтобы удалить из тестовой системы артефакты, которые в ней могут остаться после тестирования. В общем виде это просто две функции; одна автоматически выполняется в самом начале, вторая автоматически в самом конце.

В вашем случае завершение может выглядеть (как я представляю из вашего описани) примерно "если есть карточка (т.е. тест упал и ), то удалить ее, если нет карточки, то удалить". Тогда даже после падения теста карточка будет удалена. Ну или просто перед тестами создавать новую базу, а после - очищать/удалять, не заморачиваясь на проверки.

Для pytest [на SO написано довольно много](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26405380/how-do-i-correctly-setup-and-teardown-for-my-pytest-class-with-tests).

Comment: Мне такой подход кажется ненадёжным: из-за багов или изменений логики в базе могут остаться вторая карточка, журнал изменений и прочая дребедень, которую teardown мог забыть почистить и которая потом будет мешаться в других тестах. А вот от truncate не спрячется никто)

Comment: какой именно подход-то? никто не мешает в начале просто создать новую базу (или развернуть из бэкапа или еще как), а в конце просто удалить, вместе со всем что там осталось.

Comment: Конечно не мешает, но в ответе написано не это)

Comment: добавил, теперь то :)

Comment: Ну про этих двоих "test setup и test teardown" я знал, они отсылают скорее к "Самостоятельно писать sql запрос на удаление записи", просто поднимать базу целиком казалось громоздким(хотя я не пробовал). А нет такой темы в тестировочных кругах, хранить базу в докере или типо того, контейнер все-ровно стартует с одного и того же места каждый раз. Или выигрыш по скорости и удобству минимальный?

Comment: почему самостоятельно-то? Делаете функцию, которая удаляет все, что нужно удалить. Ничего не надо самостоятельно писать. Можно и в докере хранить, а в сетапе просто запускать контейнер.